# Google VM - process persistence

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform

I have a Google VM, and i can start a web server. The command i issue is: python `server.py`.
My plan is to have the application running.

Since i will eventually close my pc (and thus the terminal), will the application continue running normally?

Or, do i have to start the server and then use `disown`, to make the app run in the background?

NOTE: If the second option is the case, does this mean that when i re-log in, and i want to shut down the server, the only way to do it is with `pkill`?

Comment: If you use `disown` and then disconnect your ssh session, your program will fail as the program is still connected to the "terminal". Use a program like `tmux`. Note: running a public server with `python server.py` is a bad idea.

Comment: @JohnHanley I just want to have a server running. 1. Why is `python server.py` a bad idea? 2. If i just type the afforementioned command and close the terminal, then will the server continue running on the VM?